# ld: library not found for -lgomp, at Installing SPAMS

Tags: xcode, sparse-matrix, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to install SPAMS (SPArse Modeling Software) but I got this

```
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

mex: link of ' "./build//mexTrainDL.mexmaci64"' failed.
```

I'm compiling with matlab R2013a in MAC OS, I have installed Xcode and Intel MKL. But keep getting this error, any helps please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved for me after changing the use_multithread to false in compile.m file

Comment: Thanks I didn't read the comment in that line, it worked fine

Comment: Is there a way of using it with more than one thread (i.e., ``use_multithread=true``) ?

Comment: I'm sorry the delay, you need to change the compiler in line 18, as mex is not compatible with it (i.e., `compiler='icc';`)